# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.derby.iapi.services.property.PropertyUtil

Tags: jakarta-ee, netbeans, glassfish, derby, classnotfoundexception

When I create a Java web application in Netbeans and try to deploy and run it, then the following exception is been thrown:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/derby/iapi/services/property/PropertyUtil
    at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.NetworkServerControlImpl.getPropertyInfo(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.NetworkServerControlImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.drda.NetworkServerControl.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.derby.iapi.services.property.PropertyUtil
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    ... 3 more
```

Clean and Build is working fine. Earlier, I used to successfully deploy and run another Java web application on the machine where I am facing problem now.

I was using Netbeans 7.1. I tried to upgrade to Netbeans 7.3, but that didn't solve the problem. I also tried to put the MySQL Connector/J JAR file in `/lib` folder of Glassfish, but that didn't solve the problem.

Comment: what NB version do you have , try to upgrade to 7.3 https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=189637

Comment: @Daniel : NB 7.1. Yeah I am trying that only now (download in progress). But earlier, JSF project used to RUN on that machine.

Comment: Which application server are you using? This happened to me once, I was using Glassfish and Netbeans gave me the same error, but missing PostgreSQL driver. I fixed it putting the driver (.jar) on the /lib folder inside the Glassfish installation.

Comment: @DiogoMoreira : I am using Glassfish & NetBeans. Using mysql and have mysql driver.

Comment: Do you have MySQL driver in the /lib folder inside the Glassfish installation?

Comment: @DiogoMoreira : I went in Netbeans>>glassfish-3.1.2>>glassfish>>lib. Which jar file should i look? mysql-xxxxx.jar? If yes, I don't have  that jar file.

Comment: In your case, you have a Derby dependency, right? Try add this dependency (.jar) in the /lib folder.

Comment: @DiogoMoreira : I don't have any Derby dependency... Hence I am not getting from where I got this error...

Comment: Looks like a problem in your GlassFish installation when trying to start Apache Derby (most known as JavaDB) embedded database. This means that maybe some jar was deleted accidentally or your GF installation was corrupted somehow. The best would be reinstalling GlassFish only or searching the jars that were lost and put them in the right place.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza : may be... I will check today. I will check javadb/lib folder first... I think he is missing those files.

Comment: Dudes, Derby != MySQL. Look at the package name of the missing class. That's from Derby, not from MySQL.

Comment: @BalusC : I checked javadb/lib folder... All derby jar files are present there. I mentioned mysql jar file as Diogo mentioned that...

Comment: @BalusC : ANy idea why I am getting this error?

Comment: @FahimParkar: You might want to run `find javadb/lib -name *.jar -exec grep 'org/apache/derby/iapi/services/property/PropertyUtil' {} \;` command to check if the `PropertyUtil` exists in your libs.

Comment: @ericson : ohh... may be then... I will change the derby jar file then...

Comment: Oh, you're using Mac. That explains everything. Google gives the following link as 1st hit on ["mac+netbeans+javadb"](http://google.com/search?q=mac+netbeans+javadb) http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/java-db.html

Comment: @BalusC : Java DB link not working... :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only problem was on that machine is, **someone delete Java.** :(

Answer (score 3):

There are two basic reasons to get a ClassNotFoundException for a Derby class:

1. You are missing one of the Derby jars in your CLASSPATH. For example, you might have put derbynet.jar in your CLASSPATH but not have derby.jar.
2. You have multiple copies of the Derby jars in your CLASSPATH, and the versions are incompatible. For example, you might have two different Derby.jar classes in your classpath, and the older one is incompatible with the newer one.

Three things can make this still more complicated:

1. Derby's jar files are often bundled into other packages. For example, I believe that there is a copy of Derby bundled with Glassfish itself, so there might be a conflict between the version of Derby that is bundled with Glassfish and the version that you have packaged with your application
2. With modern versions of Java, the Java virtual machine itself will "autoload" the Derby JDBC drivers at startup, meaning that sometimes Derby already gets loaded before you intended it to be loaded, which can complicate your ability to control which version of Derby you are using.
3. Java-EE class path rules are complicated, with the application's running classpath being constructed from per-application classpath locations, application-server-provided classpath locations, and system classpath locations.

The Derby 'sysinfo' tool is designed to help with diagnosing CLASSPATH issues, so you can try using it to get a more complete picture of what copies of the Derby jars are being found on your classpath.

Hope this helps!